# How to get the Request Headers using the Chrome Devtool Protocol

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, chromium

The new chrome versions 72+ does not send the [requestHeaders](https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Network) .

there was a [solution](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/issues/3436):

> DevTools Protocol network inspection is located quite high in the network stack. This architecture doesn't let us collect all the headers that are added to the requests. So the ones we report in Network.requestWillBeSent and Network.requestIntercepted are not complete; this will stay like this for the foreseeable future.
>   There are a few ways to get real request headers:
>
> • the crude one is to use proxy
>
> • the more elegant one is to rely on Network.responseReceived DevTools protocol event. The actual headers are reported there as requestHeaders field in the Network.Response.

This worked fine with the old chromes but not with the last versions. here is a small summery I made for the versions a coulded test
[image]

a solution for chrome v67 was to add this flags to disable [Site Isolation](https://www.chromium.org/Home/chromium-security/site-isolation#TOC-Known-Issues) :

`chrome --disable-site-isolation-trials --disable-features=IsolateOrigins,site-per-process --disable-web-security`

Now all of this does not work with the last chrome v73
maybe it is caused by this:

> [Issue 932674](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=932674#c5): v72 broke devtools request interception inside cross-domain iframes
>
> you can use Fetch protocol domain that is available since m74

the solution gaven does not work neither, the [Fetch.requestPaused](https://vanilla.aslushnikov.com/?Fetch.requestPaused) does not contain the request headers...

I found some info that maybe causes that:

> [DevTools](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!searchin/devtools-reviews/Headers/devtools-reviews/HW5MVyicC3M/TRUb-_qoAgAJ): do not expose raw headers for cross-origin requests
>
> [DevTools](https://chromium-review.googlesource.com/c/chromium/src/+/821410/): do not report raw headers and cookies for protected subresources. In case subresource request's site needs to have its document protected, don't send raw headers and cookies into the frame's renderer.

or it is caused when it is an HTTP/2 server?

> Does the HTTP/2 header frame factor into a response’s encodedDataLength? (Remote Debugging Protocol)
>
> ...`headersText` is undefined for HTTP/2 requests
>   [link](https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/devtools-dev/18h17LHzF6U)

**1-** How can I get the Request Headers using the Chrome Devtool Protocol with chrome v73+?

**2-** Can a webextension solve that?

**3-** Is there another way which will be stable and last longuer? like tshark+sslkeylogfile which I'm attempting to avoid. thank you

Comment: An extension can use chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived event with 'extraHeaders' parameter optionally.